# ES6 Classes: Bind "this" to nested functions

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, this

I have multiple nested functions in a ES6 Class. Now I wonder how I can easily bind *this* of the class instance to all the subfunctions.

I know of...

```
subfunction1.bind(this)();
```

...but it feels like an awkward solution for multiple nested functions.

**Does anyone know of a more elegant solution?**

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  mainFunction() {
    console.log(this.name);//"Paul"
    
    //In order for the nested functions to get "this" it is needed to bind it 
    //to the subfunction as shown below. Is there an easier way to achieve
    //this for all the subfunctions at once?
    
    subfunction1.bind(this)();
    subfunction2.bind(this)();
    
    function subfunction1() {
      console.log(this.name);//"Paul"
    }
    
    function subfunction2() {
      console.log(this.name);//"Paul"
    }
  }
}
const paul = new User("Paul");
paul.mainFunction();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arrow functions. They work in rather a similar manner.
The arrow notation will replace this with the value of the context of the arrow function's scope.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  getSummary() {
    console.log(this.name);
    const subfunction1 = () => {
      console.log(this.name);//"Paul"
    }
    const subfunction2 = () => {
      console.log(this.name);//"Paul"
    }
    subfunction1();
    subfunction2();
  }
}
const paul = new User("Paul");
paul.getSummary();
```

Comment: Indeed. Arrow functions are the perfect solution for this. You would probably gain more votes if you would include the user's code with the necessary adaptations.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I thought If he looks up the arrow function and tries it himself. I will keep this in mind from next time.

Comment: Thanks @Innomight! I added the code to your answer. Hope I have understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a local variable that will be in the subfunctions' scope, and use that instead of `this`.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  mainFunction() {
    const self = this;
    console.log(this.name);//"Paul"
       
    subfunction1();
    subfunction2();
    
    function subfunction1() {
      console.log(self.name);//"Paul"
    }
    
    function subfunction2() {
      console.log(self.name);//"Paul"
    }
  }
}
const paul = new User("Paul");
paul.mainFunction();
```

Comment: In ES5, yes. But not when using ES6 classes.

Comment: @Bergi Is that a reply to a comment that was deleted before I read it? If it's a comment about my answer, I don't understand.

Comment: It's about the answer (maybe it's a continuations of trincot's comment on the other answer). I think that one should not use this rather dated approach in ES6 where arrow functions are available. Declaring a `self` variable was ok in ES5.

Comment: @Bergi I've never gotten comfortable with defining functions by assignment instead of the `function` declaration. I dislike that they're not hoisted so that order is important. I was going to add an arrow function alternative, but innomight already posted his answer.

Comment: So I mainly use arrow functions for anonymous callbacks, rarely for named functions.